# Azure AD B2C - customize the UI of an Azure AD Custom Identity Provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

We have 2 separate Azure Tenants. One is a parent organisations and the other is ours. Ours has a directory that has Azure AD B2C. We would like to use the parents organisation Azure AD as an Custom Identity Provider. We have got this configured and working. However, we would like to customize the UI of the parents organisation Azure AD as the branding needs to be different.

Is there a way to customize the UI of a Custom Identity Provider in Azure AD B2C? Note, we do have limited access the the parent organisations Azure AD but we are not able to change the branding/UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do this *with* Azure AD B2C since AAD B2C doesn't *own* that federated IdP. Its up to the federated IdP to provide the branding. For Azure AD, the branding abilities are documetented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding).

Comment: Yeah, figured as much. Was just being hopeful :)